# Building and deploying Asp.net application using Azure devops pipeline

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I am trying to build and deploy a Asp.net 4.0 application using Azure dev ops. I want to create a separate dll per aspx page. So in the build parameters of the pipeline, i have the following

```
/t:Rebuild /p:OutputPath=bin /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:WebPublishMethod="FileSystem"
/p:PublishProvider="FileSystem" /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=True /p:EnableUpdateable=False 
**/p:DebugSymbols=True /p:UseMerge=True /p:DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles=True 
/p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:WDPMergeOption="CreateSeparateAssembly"** /p:UseFixedNames=True 
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=True /p:Configuration=Release /p:LastUsedPlatform="Any CPU" 
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=True
/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

Inspite of setting create separate assembly i am not able to see separate dlls for every aspx page. Can someone help here

Comment: All that i am trying to acheive is the answer given in this link https://forums.asp.net/t/2126330.aspx?How+to+compile+my+ASP+Net+aspx+and+cs

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide a complete run log, so that we can investigate this question further. (Set the varibale `system.debug` to `true` to get full debug logs.)